# Wordpress Bedrock breaking plugin links

Tags: directory, composer, wp-dependencies

I recently switched to using WP-Bedrock and I currently like the workflow but there's a huge drawback for me.

There are 2 URLs which previously were identical, due to Bedrock's file structure, are different.
Site_URL: /wp
Home_URL:

A huge bunch of plugins are written taking in mind only regular WP installations.

A very critical plugin for my site is currently unusable because the links to internal images look like this:

`https://<domain>/wp/https://<domain>/app/uploads/...`

I've tried to dig in the plugin files but It's not that easy for customization.

Another friend suggested that I do a 301 redirect in my Apache config, but I couldn't figure out how to correctly set it up without breaking my site.

Current plugin in mind: [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-products-configurator-for-woocommerce/)

I haven't found any alternatives to this so It's crucial that I get this working.

Comment: Have you asked [in the official support forums of the plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/visual-products-configurator-for-woocommerce/)? We're also using Bedrock for projects and haven't had this problem yet. The simple solution would be to go back to the old structure and switch to Bedrock once the plugins are working with it

Comment: @kero I'm on support with them directly but they can't help that much. And the thing is that it's not just this plugin. NextGEN Gallery also had this issue. I had this on like 3 or 4 plugins and on most of them I configured the source files to work but this plugin is a bit everywhere so It's a bit harder to keep track where goes what.

Comment: Are you sure your setup is 100% accurate? Maybe the [Roots Discourse](https://discourse.roots.io/) can help them. I think this Q&A is the wrong place, as your question is about a plugin (which is off topic) and in general quite difficult (without access / without very Bedrock-specific knowledge) to help you here.

Comment: Dunno... ...Bedrock claims it provides 'easier configuration'... ...but this doesn't seem easier.